# Conditionally load AngularJS component

Tags: angularjs

I have a component for my responsive view:

```
<responsive-navigation></responsive-navigation>
```

I want to only load this component when the app is not loaded on a desktop view. Through the `current-device` library I can detect the current device. So in the `$onInit` of the component I have:

```
public $onInit() {
    console.log(!window.device.desktop());
}
```

This works fine. Is it possible to use the `current-device` data to conditionally load the component?

Answer (score 0):

Do the device check out of the component. You can add a boolean to `$rootScope`, as it is a global app information:

```
$rootScope.isDesktop = window.device.desktop();
```

Then, using `ng-if` you can load the component conditionally:

```
<responsive-navigation ng-if="::!isDesktop"></responsive-navigation>
```